# How to save positon of draggable with Metro UI CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, metro-ui-css

With Metro UI CSS creating a [draggable](http://metroui.org.ua/draggable.html) is pretty easy:

```
<div data-role="draggable"></div>
```

It's fun for the end user to drag an element like this, and it would be even nice if I could save the position of draggable (after being dragged) for the user's next visit. So how can I do this?

Comment: With these type of things it's typical in which javascript handles it's css as a style attribute (and does so in this case). You could just save it's style attribute in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: @MichaelSchwartz how should I detect when the element is being dragged, using JavaScript so that I can save it?

Comment: Yes with JavaScript you can use [mouse or touch events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/) to detect when the element is being dragged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these type of things it's typical in which javascript handles it's css as a style attribute (and does so in this case). You could just save it's style attribute in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box" data-role="draggable"></div>
```

**JavaScript/JQuery:**

```
if ( localStorage.getItem("elmPos")) {
  $(".box").attr("style", localStorage.getItem("elmPos"))
}

$(".box").on("mousedown touchstart mousemove touchmove mouseup touchend", function() {
  localStorage.setItem("elmPos", $(".box").attr("style"))
})
```